# How to Programmatically Set the Client Callback Address in netTcpBindings

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, nettcpbinding, wcf-endpoint

I'm currently working on a service that involves client callback over `netTcpBinding`. However, I can't find answers to the following two questions:

1. When a client invokes the service, what is the client's address that will be used for callback?
2. How can I programmatically change this address before the client invokes the service?

I understand that when working with `wsDualHttpBindings`, there is a property called `clientBaseAddress` that can be used to set the client address. However, `netTcpBinding` doesn't have a similar property?

Comment: `NetTcpBinding` is duplex out of the box.  `wsDualHttpBinding` is actually two HTTP channels - one from the client to the service and one from the service to the client (for callbacks), which is why there is a `clientBaseAddress` for `wsDualHttpBinding`.  It's not needed for truly duplex channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netTcpBinding` is bi-directional, so you don't need to do anything to specify the client's address.

The reason you have to specify it for `wsDualHttpBinding` is because that binding establishes 2 HTTP channels (since HTTP isn't bi-directional) - one for the client to the service, and the second one for the service to the client.

So to answer your questions:

1. The address that will be used for the callbacks is the address of the client.
2. You don't need to change the callback address with `netTcpBinding`. Indeed, you wouldn't want to change it for `wsDualHttpBinding` either - I think you meant how would you set it in code, and in this case you can't and don't need to.

Comment: In case if either the connection is closed or either the client or service crashes, is it possible to reestablish the connection *only* when the service needs to use the callback?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you mean you can turn  the connection on and off as needed for callbacks, I would think most likely not.  NetTcpBinding is bi-directional so the callback "ability" is always there, whether its used or not.  Note also that the client initiates the connection - the service cannot initiate the connection simply to send the callback.